# boost::shared_array and aligned memory allocation

Tags: c++, boost, memory-management, sse2

In Visual C++, I'm trying to dynamically allocate some memory which is 16-byte aligned so I can use SSE2 functions that require memory alignment.  Right now this is how I allocate the memory:

`boost::shared_array aData(new unsigned char[GetSomeSizeToAllocate()]);`

I know I can use _aligned_malloc to allocate aligned memory, but will that cause a problem with boost when it tries to free my memory?  This is the code boost uses to free the memory:

`template inline void checked_array_delete(T * x)
{
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
    (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
    delete [] x;
}`

Memory free'd by delete must be allocated with new, right?  Any tip on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::shared_array` has a constructor that takes a deleter as a second argument to be used instead of default `delete[]`.

This means you might be able to pass the address of a suitable deallocation function just like that.

```
boost::shared_array<X> array(allocate_x(100), &deallocate_x);
```

References: [Boost.SharedArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)